# WPF Application : Textbox text selection like we do in browsers

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, itemscontrol

My Application structure is attached in picture[Requiremnent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKdDK.png)

requirement 1: draw a rectagle to show area covered by mouse . here yellow rectangle

requirement 2: copy text under the yellow rectangle to clip board

1. yellow rectangle could be in one text box
   or
2. yellow rectangle could be across multiple text boxes

this yellow rectangle is drawn using mouse left button down - mouse move- mouse up.

This requirement is something similar like when we select a data in browser[sample image of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9LAW.png)Ex. here consider 3 different text boxes. I would like to copy text in blue here.

How to achieve this using WPF?

Textboxes in my case are like

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mvvm:MVVMText}">
            <TextBox Name="Text" Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=OneWay,   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                    IsReadOnly="True" >
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>


<Grid>

                  <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" >

                        <ItemsControl.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.Template>

                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" MinWidth="550" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                      
                    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Drawing a rectangle+copying text under it is quite different than select+copy in a web browser or in a text box. TextBox already has built in text selection support that is similar to a web browser, the main difference being you can't continuously copy across multiple TextBoxes like you can with `div`s. So I think you need to be a little clearer on what kind of selection action you're going for. But I'll also say that manual text selection in WPF (or anything) is quite challenging.

Comment: I understood that rectangle+copy is different then select+copy. Let's say that I want to select and copy behavior but across the multiple text boxes. Should I need to redesign the way  I was doing for multiple textboxes with Data template?

Comment: Yeah sorry I don't know of a way to do that in WPF. I imagine it might require getting very deep into the guts of TextBox and its children, probably subclassing one or more of them if not totally re-implementing them, and devising some way of linking the selection state of multiple TextBoxes. Definitely not trivial.